# Firing Squad Escape Scene

Tags: fiction, combat

Is it possible for a highly trained elite soldier to escape a firing squad?

Details:
The soldier asks for a blindfold and the MP obliges. The MP walks over and the soldier headbutts the MP's crotch. The soldier uses the disabled MP as a meat shield and uncuffs his hands. The soldier takes the MP's sidearm and shoots the rest of the MPs. Is this a realistic scenario?

Comment: This is likely the wrong SE to ask for critiques on the realism of a scene, WorldBuilding would be a better fit but as is it's still likely to be closed there

Comment: 1) No, it's not realistic.  2) It's not right for Writing.SE.  While I agree that Worldbuilding is a better choice, I also agree with @BKlassen that it would be closed there.  Basically, you're telling a story and you get to decide what's going to happen, however implausible.

Answer (score 3):

Your scenario is kind of unrealistic..

1. How do you head butt someone in the crotch?  Are they executing Tyrion Lannister?
2. if it is an elite super soldier that is being executed, the members of the firing squad would know they are dealing with an elite soldier.  And presumably they would take some precaution.
3. How would you account for the number of people involved in the firing squad, and the guards nearby?
4. it is much easier to escape before getting to the execution ground.  (and it is far easier to do if he has outside help)

Comment: They don't know he is an elite soldier the system he was trained by was disbanded and top secret.

Comment: @Neo1009: unless he was a little person it would still be hard to head butt someone in the crotch.